# Putting datatable comma separated values in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

My datatable consists of a column named "ID". The no. of values in this column varies.Sometimes this Datatable fetches 3 IDs in that ID column, sometimes 2.
Now if for example, my datatable has three values as 1,2,3. What I want is to put these three values in a string and separate them by commas as folows:-

```
string test= "1,2,3";
```

If Datatable has 2 values, then string should be as follows:-

```
string test= "1,2";
```

I did try but in vain. Please help. Thanks.

edit:-

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable;
 dt = obj.GetIDs();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                { 
                string test= "What should be here????";
                }
```

**edit 2**

```
 foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string str = str + "," + Convert.ToString(dr("ID"));

            }
```

@Rajeev ::Tried this..it says dr is a variable but used as a method. What's wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that sometimes three rows are fetched, or that the content of the ID column for one row in the database contains the value "1,2,3" for example?

Comment: Do you have an example of your code in progress?

Comment: @Oyvind:: Yes,I meant that sometimes 3 rows are fetched, sometimes2 in the datatable.

Comment: @Oded:: I have edited it.Sorry.

Comment: @Serenity regarding your latest edit: you're using dr as if it's a function that gets a string passed as a parameter; maybe `dr["ID"]` will work better, although I doubt it. Try using another foreach inside the first one to iterate over the elements in dr: `foreach(var s in dr)  str += s.ToString() + ", ";`

Comment: Use square brackets like : dr["ID"] instead of dr("ID"). That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string output;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    output = output + dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
    output += (i < dt.Rows.Count) ? "," : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: `string output;` should be `string output = string.Empty;` or `= ""` according to my Visual Studio 2015 IDE.

Answer (score 17):

Just a one liner using *LINQ*.

```
String result = table.AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(row => row["ID"].ToString())
                     .Aggregate((s1, s2) => String.Concat(s1, "," + s2));
```

Comment: A one-liner indeed, but that is a *very* long line ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using linq, do it like this:

```
var idlist = table.AsEnumerable().Select( r => r.Field<string>("ID")).ToArray();
string result = string.Join(",", idlist);
```

This one fixes your last example

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   string str = str + "," + Convert.ToString(dr["ID"]);
}
```

Your problem is that you are trying to call `dr("ID")`, but dr is not a method as implied by your syntax. Use `dr["ID"]` instead to get the ID column of your row.

However, this last approach also would give the result ",1,2,3", so you better rewrite it like this (or use my LINQ variant):

```
List<string> myIds = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   myIds.Add( Convert.ToString(dr["ID"]));
}
string result = string.Join(",", myIds);
```

Comment: I'd give you a +1 if it weren't the code does not compile. LinQ's Select returns a EnumerableRowCollection.

Comment: Ok, I researched and the correct linQ should be `string result = string.Join(",", dtBibliography.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ID")).ToArray());` What the heck, I'm feeling generous, here's your +1 **;-Þ**

Comment: @AlejoBrz - Forgot that ToArray there. Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1):

How to get datatable column to a Comma Separated string (CSV) in ASP.NET C# using Linq.

Option 1:

```
string commaSeparatedString = String.Join(",", ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Data Table Column ID").ToString()).ToArray());
```

Option 2:

```
var SelectedValues = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<int>("Data Table Column ID")).ToArray();
string commaSeperatedValues = string.Join(",", SelectedValues);
```

Note: Please import package `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a Datatable which has has n rows and 1 column (ID, that is).

If dt is the Datatable, then you could loop through the row collection, as:

```
For Each dr as DataRow in dt.Rows
  str = str + "," + Convert.ToString(dr("ID"))
Next
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: Two comments. 1) The question is tagged C#. 2) This will give a response like ",1,2,3".

Comment: Plz check my edited ques ..thnx..I have implemented like u said but there's a problem.

Comment: @Serenity, Use dr["ID"] instead of dr("ID"). My code was in VB, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

we can as also achieve this using below code.

this is my Datatable

DataTable OpDtAdPortalProcessReport = new DataTable();

```
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Columns.Add("Process Name");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Columns.Add("Processed On");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Columns.Add("Status");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Columns.Add("Comments");

        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Rows.Add("7 Miles", "", "gray", "");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Rows.Add("Active", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"), "green", "");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Rows.Add("BMW", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"), "green", "");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Rows.Add("Eicoff", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"), "green", "");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Rows.Add("Volkswagen", "", "gray", "");
        OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Rows.Add("Universal", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"), "orange", "Bot/Script failed to be Executed because of some server issue.");

        Processname = String.Join(",", OpDtAdPortalProcessReport.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => x["Status"].ToString().Contains("green")).ToList<DataRow>().Select(c=> c["Process Name"].ToString()));
```